# How is the Grub command "save_env" supposed to work?

Tags: grub2, grub

I'm trying to modify grubenv from within Grub. According to the documentation this should work by using the command [save_env](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/save_005fenv.html#save_005fenv). Unfortunately I can't get it to work.
I would like to change the value saved_entry using the following command on the Grub command line

```
save_env saved_entry=Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)
```

It does not return any error, but list_env still shows the old value.
This is on a Ubuntu 15.10 minimal install.

Am I missing on something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I luckily able to answer my own question now. :)

To use save_env one must first set the env and only then save it. (That part was not clear to me from the Grub documentation)

So the working commands look like:

```
set saved_entry='Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)'
save_env saved_entry
```

That's it!
I actually found the solution thanks to this [post](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-grub/2013-02/msg00048.html).